# Multiple solutions for {↓} ⊢ (p → r) → r

Tags: logic, hilbert-calculus

Are both of these correct?

Teacher's solution

{↓} ⊢ (p → r) → r

{↓ , (p → r)} ⊢ r

1   ((p → ↓) → ↓) → p   Ax3 F/p

2   ↓ → ((p → ↓) → ↓)   Ax2 F/↓ G/(p → ↓)

3   ↓   ∈ Σ

4   ((p → ↓) → ↓)   MP 2,3

5   p   MP 1,4

6   p → r   ∈ Σ

7 r MP 5,6

My solution

{↓} ⊢ (p → r) → r

{↓ , (p → r)} ⊢ r

1   ((r → ↓) → ↓) → r   Ax3 F/r

2   ↓ → ((r → ↓) → ↓)   Ax2 F/↓ G/(r → ↓)

3   ↓   ∈ Σ

4   ((r → ↓) → ↓)   MP 2,3

5   r   MP 1,4

Comment: What is $\{ ↓ \}$ ?

Comment: Hilbert-calculus means "axioms+rules": what are the axioms ?

Comment: ax2 is F→(G→F)
ax3 is ((F→↓)→↓)→F

Comment: It seems to me that ↓ is [$\bot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both derivations seem correct to me. It might seem strange to you that you didn't need to use $(p \to r)$ to arrive at the right answer, but when $\bot$ is a hypothesis, [everything is easy to prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)!

In fact, you've essentially discarded the $p \to r$ and proved the principle of explosion $\bot \to r$.